# Want to learn more about "Find Files on Desktop"

Tags: 22.04

On Ubuntu 22.04. I recently discovered that if you're on the desktop, and just start typing, a Find Files on Desktop box appears that highlights the matching file/icon on the Desktop with what you've typed in, here's how it shows up for me:
[image]

I want to learn more about this feature:

- If there's a keyboard shortcut to invoke this search box
- If there are customization options available
- If I can set it's timeout (it auto times out and disappears, which is pretty fast for me)

I searched online but surprisingly could not find any mentions of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there's a keyboard shortcut to invoke this search box

<kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> performs that function.

Comment: Is this on Wayland? Afaik those shortcuts got removed.  It does not work on my 23.04 :)

Comment: Works on my 23.04 (Wayland).

Comment: The OP asked about 22.04 where the shortcut does work (tested using Wayland and on 23.04 Wayland)

Comment: Commenting on a random post of yours so you see this: network consensus is to not edit spam https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/1081494 and to rollback to the spam if the spam is edited out https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306458/1081494 - unless there’s either a new MSE consensus or Meta AU post superseding that, I intend to rollback edits that remove spam.

Comment: @cocomac all well and good, but that was before the mod strike. When the mods end their action, normal service will be resumed and the spam actors will themselves be removed.